# How to create an automator workflow/application to delete jpeg when raw exist

Tags: raw

I know this has been covered over the years but no harm in an update perhaps there are more expedient techniques.

I have approx 1 terabyte of Canon CR2 images in 40 sub-folders, some with matching jpeg and some just jpeg.

I want to delete all jpegs that have a matching corresponding raw .cr2 file.

I would like to mac automator or a script run through terminal.

I tried some of the tips from an older article but the scripts has syntax errors.

[How to delete JPG files, but only if the matching RAW file exists?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16401/how-to-delete-jpg-files-but-only-if-the-matching-raw-file-exists)

I get an error Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”.

apologies but the syntax error persists

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "*.CR2" suffix

find . -type f -iname "*.${suffix}" | \
while read line
do
  lowercase=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/${suffix}/jpg/gi")
  uppercase=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/${suffix}/JPG/gi")

  if [ -f "${lowercase}" ]
  then
    rm -v "${lowercase}"
  elif [ -f "${uppercase}" ]
  then
    rm -v "${uppercase}"
  else
    echo "${line}: no jpg present"
  fi
done
```

Comment: How you can be sure the files (CR2 and JPEG) are the same? Compare content?

Comment: Exif data can be compared, the timestamps are equal for both jpeg and raw files.

Comment: EXIF data is just text included in to the file. There is no problem to copy EXIF records from one file and write them to another file.

Comment: I understand you saw this question already, but syntax errors are not a reason to pose a duplicate question. Can you indicate what the syntax errors are? Maybe you can do so in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat)?

Comment: If you specifically require an Automator action, perhaps this question would be better asked at the Apple Stack, [apple.se]. Otherwise, I'm inclined to agree this is a duplicate of the linked question. I won't close this question as a dupe (I'll let the community decide if it's a dupe). If you want us to migrate this to [apple.se], just ask (rather than cross-post over there), we'll make it happen. Thanks. =)

Comment: Will be wise to ask programming questions in Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks I have posted the question on ask different https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408672/how-to-create-an-automator-workflow-application-to-delete-jpeg-when-raw-exist